# How to come to know that my hibernate is using c3p0 connection pool which i mentioned in configuration file?

Tags: hibernate

```
<hibernate-configuration>  

    <session-factory>  
        <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>  
        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect</property>  
        <property name="connection.url">jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe</property>  
        <property name="connection.username">SYSTEM</property>  
        <property name="connection.password">oracle</property>  
        <property name="connection.driver_class">oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver</property> 

        <property name="hibernate.
connection.provider_class">org.hibernate.connection.C3P0ConnectionProvider</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size">7</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size">53</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout">100</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements">50</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period">1000</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.validate">true</property>

   <!--  <mapping resource="employee.hbm.xml"/>  -->
    <mapping class="com.rest.text.Employee"/>
    </session-factory>  

</hibernate-configuration>
```

Actually I have configured c3p0 connection pool in my hibernate configuration file,I am able to access the database also, but i just want to know it is using the c3p0 connection pool or its own connection? How to know that?

Answer (score 0):

You can turn on [c3p0 logging](http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/#configuring_logging), and check the logs.